# Temporal trigger in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Is it possible to define a temporal (i.e. time/date based trigger) in PostgreSQL?

Consider I store a table with some data, that also contains a field for `timestamp`.
This timestamp field is the date/time that I want a certain function to be triggered?

Is it possible to associate a trigger with this table, that can execute the desired trigger at the given time?

Answer (score 1):

This is what [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent.html) does.

Answer (score 1):

Or use cron-jobs on a UNIX / LINUX systems. Something like

```
psql -p5432 mydb -c 'SELECT myfunction()'
```

as system user `postgres` which is set up to log in without password.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Triggers are only fired through SQL statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)